# Inheritance issue with pointers?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a header file to a library that I can't touch but have to add functionality to it.
So I will just inherit the AA class to the library.  But running into issues with class pointer and the constructor.  Not sure how to make the bridge over to it.

```
class AA : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    static AA* GetInstance();
private:
    explicit AA(QObject* parent = 0);
};
```

---

```
class BB : AA
{
private:
    explicit BB(QObject* parent = 0):AA(parent)
{
    //some more functionality added once this class is instantiated.
}
}
```

---

```
class CC : BB
{
    ...

connect(BB::GetInstance(),
              SIGNAL(cxOnline(bool)),
              this,
              SLOT(OnCxOnline(bool)));  //this error out: static AA* AA::GetInstance() is inaccessible within this context 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can yo be clearer about these "issues" youre running into?

Comment: You can't inherit from a function pointer, just as you can't inherit from a pointer or an integer.

Comment: static "AA* GetInstance();" is a class pointer but I can't just connect to it leaving the contents of the BB class blank.

Comment: @jdl You are stuck here if `AA` has a private constructor.  There is no way for a derived class to call it.

Comment: There are no function pointers in this example.

Comment: made updates to the problem

Comment: added the initializer

Comment: @quamrana, what about throught the GetInstance ?

Comment: @jdl The `GetInstance` method is static and cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

class `AA` is designed to be:

- a singleton (or is that just a factory, I can't tell from the description provided -- but if it is a factory it's a poor one, since I can't tell how the object should be freed)
- non-inheritable

What you're trying to do has been explicitly and intentionally prevented by the author of the class (the constructor is private not protected).

(There may be a loophole -- I don't see anything making `AA` non-copyable, unless all `QObject` instances are non-copyable.  After some checking, if this is the Qt `QObject` then yes it is non-copyable.)

If you ever design a class which only you can create (singleton or object factory), it's a good idea to provide a policy hook that allows changing the type of the constructed object.  This is part of the IoC (inversion of control) pattern and greatly contributes to testing (you can insert a mock object) and extensibility.

In your circumstance where `AA` cannot be altered, you should consider using composition for reuse, instead of inheritance.